# How to disable direct update MFP 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using the following configuration on my local host to disable direct update, but the direct update shows up randomly.

```
 <securityTests>
    <customSecurityTest name="iOSSecurityTest">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test mode="disabled" realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/>
        <test isInternalDeviceID="true" realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to disable direct update ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things:

1. Remove the `wl_directUpdateRealm` test altogether from the security test
2. Experiment with the expiration value of `wl.realm.expiration.directUpdate` in worklight.properties, as it is this value that dictates [*when* will the direct update check take place](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/#underTheHood).

Either way it sounds like you may want to open a PMR to have it checked by the development team why "disable" is not working.

Note that if this is in an external server you must re-deploy the .war file if making any changes to any file under the "server" folder.

Comment: I am testing this solution and i will keep you posted. I have tried so many hacks and let see if this is going to fix. I will accept it as an answer once i go through couple of testing. Again, thanks for the fast response.